# Where is joomla main page

Tags: html, joomla

Web sites built by the simple way often have a main html document that the html code is written in it.
If a user right clicks on the browser and select "view page source" then the name : "Example.html" will appear as page source.
That file then can be found in the web site's root directory.

My question is : what about joomla? Where is that main file?
What if I want to put some code in the page that I see on the front end, where do I do that?

Comment: i think you should go through MVC(model view controller) and JOOMLA MVC it will help you how figure out your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla doesn't contain any html files for displaying content, the only html files you will find are blank.

Joomla uses 2 index.php files. There is one in the template folder where all the HTML, CSS and Javascript is pushed to and the other is in the root of your Joomla site where all applications get pushed to one loaded.

When you view the page source code for a Joomla site, you are simply viewing the structure that has been pushed to the index.php file from various locations, such as from modules and components.

**Update**

Ok, I think this might be best done in the index.php file of your template. First, in the Joomla backend, get the ID of the menu item that link to the page that you wish to use for your code. Once done, add the following code to the index.php:

```
<?php

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$menu = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->id;

if ( $menu == 1) { // change 1 to the ID that you got from the Menu Manager
    $doc->addStyleDeclaration('
        //css goes here
    ');
    $doc->addScriptDeclaration('
        //javascript code goes here
    ');
    ?>

    <p>hello world</p>

    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, Lodder. So if I were to make some changes and add some code css html and js then how would I place and where that code in order to be excecuted in the front main page?  Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what exactly you wanted to do. Please explain in more detail what changes you wish to make and I can give you a more accurate answer

Comment: Thanks Lodder.   Actually this is the thing: 1. I have a code that has css, html and js. I need to put it in jommla but in a specific page not on all. Is there a way to tell joomla to read that code when user clicks on a specific page of the web site? I am more concerned on reading the javascript.

Comment: I have already put that code in the index.php and successfully calls the whole thing. The css and js are in the root. My issue is that I need it to be executed on a specific page only

Comment: I will reply when I get back home from work ;) is your custom code for site bevaviour? Or is it something extra such as a widget? My answer may vary depending on what it is.

Comment: wow, thanks for the code!  Let me work on it. I will get back later. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks a lot! Your code works just fine! You are great! I have one more question about this matter, I dont know if I have to make another post but is related... so.. when I write in the wysiwyg editor then the data on the editor end up somewhere and then posted in front end. My question is where do those data end up? What file? If I could edit that then I could bypass the data compilation/cropping of the editor

Comment: Any data that gets saved, is always saved to the database. In this case (assuming you are using the default Joomla article manager), the data/articles (includes your code in the article) get saved to the database table called `#__content`. `#__` is the prefix for all tables so the actual table name may look something like `jos_content`

Comment: Hello Lodder, I have posted again the above question about where the code ends up in order to close the original question. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512924/where-the-content-of-joomla-custom-html-is