# where the content of Joomla custom html is?

Tags: joomla, customization

When I write in the wysiwyg editor then the data in the editor end up somewhere and then posted in front end. My question is where do those data end up? How do I access them via filezilla? What is the directory?

Thank you,

Best Regards,

Andreas Achilleos

Comment: Do you mean in a custom html module? It's in the modules table.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming and the poster does not know what a database is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any data that gets saved, is always saved to the database. In this case (assuming you are using the default Joomla article manager), the data/articles (includes your code in the article) get saved to the database table called `#__content`. `#__` is the prefix for all tables so the actual table name may look something like `jos_content`

Comment: :) I tried to explore in filezila but I could not find the directory you say!

Comment: It's not a directory, It's in the database. This can be accessed by something like PHPmyAdmin on in your control panel

Comment: ! YES, I try to find but with no luck! You say that I can access it via the control panel of the site or the CCP client control panel of cloudaccess site?

Comment: I try on the backend of the site >template manager>editor and only the basic files I can see eg css, html

Comment: Can I access it via filezilla?

Comment: Ok, forget the files, or filezilla, this has nothing to do with the database. To make life easier, which host are you using to host your website? 1and1? Godaddy? Let me know and I will be able to explain a little better for you.

Comment: Ok, Go to the Cloudaccess Control Panel here: https://ccp.cloudaccess.net/clientarea.php and login. One done, there will be an option for PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thats it! I appreciate it!